# Can I set custom DNS servers on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: 8.0, networking

I prefer to use third-party DNS servers, regardless of what network I'm on, for various reasons. At home, I push this configuration to everyone via DHCP. Out and about, my laptop is locked onto my desired DNS servers no matter what DHCP serves up.

Is there a way to set a static DNS server configuration on my phone?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is an option, if you tap and hold on the wireless network you are connected to and choose "edit" all the text fields are grayed out. I am unable to do anything except add a proxy server. Though, if there is no DHCP I expect these to be editable. Too bad there does no appear to be a manual override.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

1. Go to Settings -> WiFi
2. Enable proxy
3. For the server/URL, enter your preferred DNS setting
4. For the port, enter your port number if known or 80 which is default